# Count number of subs in procedure for progress bar

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar, procedure

I have my template which changes the statusbar in de bottom-left corner of the excel screen when the template is being update. Most of my colleagues probably will not notice this. Therefore, to keep them informed about the progress that is being made during excecution of the macro, I would like to create a progress bar.

Therefore, I have looked at some example and now have designed a progress bar which works fine for the code supplied. 
For my specific need, I want the progress bar to be updated each time a new sub is being called. I know the fixed number of subs that is executed during the procedure (6) and I want to have VBA check which number is being executed. after sub 1 is finished, the progress is 1/6 = 16,67%, after sub 2 it is 33% etc. etc.

I have searched for vba methods of counting how many subs are in the code and for a way to determine where in the process the procedure is.

Can I have what I would like to have?

I have these subs being called during execution of the procedure:

```
Call datawissen
Call dataplaatsen
Call kolomtitels
Call toevoegen
Call maaktabel
Call refreshpivot
```

Comment: Just have a counter variable that goes up by 1 every time you call a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible to programmatically count the number of Subs in a piece of code, it's probably beyond your needs. Most would likely do something like this:

```
total_no = 6
cnt = 0

refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call datawissen
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call dataplaatsen
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call kolomtitels
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call toevoegen
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call maaktabel
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no

Call refreshpivot
cnt = cnt + 1
refresh_bar cnt / total_no
```

Where refresh_bar is a Sub that re-draws a progress bar with a percentage complete value supplied as the parameter.

Comment: that is what I also was creating when you posted your answer: 
counter = 0
  Call datawissen
counter = counter + 1
  For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Output Totaal" Then Call ASW
    Next i

counter = counter + 1
  Call dataplaatsen

where counter would be the value that is used for the progress bar.(and divided by 6 to get a percentage)